# Does there exist a Cauchy-complete, non-Archimedean ordered field that is not isomorphic to a field extension of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: field-theory, hilbert-spaces, extension-field, complete-spaces, ordered-fields

Does there exist a metrizable non-Archimedean ordered field $\mathbb{F}$ that is Cauchy-complete under some metric $d$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is not isomorphic to any field extension of $\mathbb{R}$? I ask because I am thinking about whether the generalization of Hilbert spaces as "vector spaces over such fields, equipped with a positive-definite sesquilinear form" would allow for fields that are not isomorphic to a field extension of $\mathbb{R}$. I have done very little field theory so far, so I would appreciate detailed explanations.

If this is not possible, I would be interested in what happens if you take out the order requirement as well. Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, what exactly is your definition of "Cauchy-complete"?  Cauchy sequences are just not useful for arbitrary ordered fields (for instance, an ordered field can have *no* Cauchy sequences at all that are not eventually constant).

Comment: I just meant the traditional notion of Cauchy completeness for a metric space. As I mentioned, I have done very little field theory, so I am not particularly familiar with what an arbitrary ordered field is like and haven't put that much thought into it (yet at least). If you think there is a more refined/specific notion of completeness that would be more useful/appropriate, then I would not object to it, but I definitely do want the field to at least be Cauchy complete, yet still non-Archimedean (so that we're not just talking about ${\mathbb{R}}$).

Comment: A non-Archimedean ordered field does not have any natural metric space structure, so the usual notion for metric spaces does not apply.

Comment: You are right, I should have specified that it's a metrizable field and we have a metric as well, under which the field is Cauchy complete. I will edit it for clarity, but not the title since it is already long enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, let me comment on the "correct" notion of Cauchy completeness for an ordered field $F$.  Given an ordinal $\xi$, say a $\xi$-indexed sequence $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\xi}$ is *Cauchy* if for each $\epsilon>0$ in $F$ there exists $\alpha<\xi$ such that $|x_\beta-x_\gamma|<\epsilon$ for all $\beta,\gamma\geq \alpha$.  Similarly, say $(x_\alpha)$ converges to $x\in F$ if for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\alpha<\xi$ such that $|x_\beta-x|<\epsilon$ for all $\beta\geq \alpha$.  Then $F$ can be called *Cauchy-complete* if all Cauchy ordinal-indexed sequences in $F$ converge to some element of $F$.  Any ordered field has a Cauchy completion obtained by formally adjoining limits to all Cauchy ordinal-indexed sequences (which can in fact be taken to all be indexed by the cofinality of $F$).

(There are many equivalent formulations of this notion, such as using nets or filters instead of ordinal-indexed sequences.  Another equivalent formulation is that a Dedekind cut $(L,R)$ in $F$ is always filled by an element of $F$ as long as either for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $x\in L$ such that $y<x+\epsilon$ for all $y\in L$ or for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $x\in R$ such that $y>x-\epsilon$ for all $y\in R$.)

In particular, for instance, consider the field $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ ordered such that $x$ is infinitely large.  This field is not Cauchy-complete, but let $F$ be its Cauchy completion.  (Since $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is countable, you can construct $F$ by just taking ordinary $\mathbb{N}$-indexed Cauchy sequences.)  Note that every element of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is either infinitely large or is infinitesimally close to some element of $\mathbb{Q}$: a rational function $f(x)/g(x)$ is infinitely large if $\deg f>\deg g$, infinitesimal if $\deg f<\deg g$, and if $\deg f=\deg g$ then it is infinitesimally close to $a/b$ where $a$ and $b$ are the leading coefficients of $f$ and $g$.  Any element in the completion $F$ can be approximated arbitrarily closely by elements of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$, which means any element of $F$ is infinitesimally close to an element of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ since $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ has infinitesimals.  Thus every element of $F$ is either infinitely large or infinitesimally close to an element of $\mathbb{Q}$.  In particular, for instance, $F$ cannot contain a square root of $2$, so $\mathbb{R}$ does not embed in $F$.

(If you insist on talking about completeness in terms of a metric, this example can also be given a metric: say $d(f,g)=2^n$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is the difference between the degrees of the numerator and denominator of $f-g$.  This defines a metric on $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ compatible with its order topology and the metric completion with respect to this metric can naturally be identified with the Cauchy completion.)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I would have to think about this for some length and study up on some things to properly understand the technical details, particularly the formal definition of ordinal numbers (I only know them informally so far), the equivalence of the forms of completeness you describe, and the method to get a Cauchy completion, but I plan to learn all these things eventually anyway.

Comment: Reading this also gave me another question: the absolute value function seems to be almost like a metric compatible with the order topology of any ordered field, except for the fact that it maps to the field itself and not R. Is there a name for a generalization of the notion of a metric so that it must satisfy all the usual axioms, except it may map to any ordered field and not just R? Or perhaps even very generally as mapping to any ordered group? I am thinking of a similar question about measures, as well. Maybe I should make this into a separate question.

Comment: I have sometimes seen such things called "generalized metrics".

Comment: Thanks! Searching for that term, I found that my question has actually already been nicely addressed on here, even:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315363/generalization-of-metric-spaces

As for measures, I found that even on Wikipedia this sort of generalization is discussed, but since we can already define measures on any sigma algebras and "contents" on basically any collection of sets, the main benefit to generalizing the codomain of measures seems to be when you want to use a specific codomain structure for some specific reasons.